# Call helpers in a Jenkins Shared Library

Tags: class, jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins Shared Library organized like that :

```
 +- src                     
 |   +- main
 |       +- jenkins_shared_library
 |           +- helpers
 |               +- GitHelper.groovy  
 |               +- ArtifactoryHelper.groovy
```

with for example the ArtifactoryHelper :

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
package main.jenkins_shared_library.helpers

/** Helper for artifactory commands */
class ArtifactoryHelper implements Serializable
{
    ArtifactoryHelper(String projectName_artifactory='', String organizationName='', String projectName='')
    {
     ...
    }

    def downloadStable()
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

How I call thess class and method into my jenkins pipelines ?

Comment: ArtifactoryHelper.downloadStable() - Can you try if this would work for you?

Comment: I got this error : `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ArtifactoryHelper for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

Comment: I think the example here with Utilities class can be of help:  https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes over it in more detail [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) but you need to import your shared library into your Jenkinsfile and then declare an instance of your class. After that you can call it.

```
@Library('somelib')
import main.jenkins_shared_library.helpers.ArtifactoryHelper

node ('build') {
    ArtifactoryHelper artifactoryHelper = new ArtifactoryHelper("projectName_artifactory", "organizationName", "projectName")
    
    stage('Download Stable') {
        artifactoryHelper.downloadStable()
    }
}
```

This assumes you already added your library as a shared library in the Jenkins management called "somelib".